# Developing a mobile app without a device to work with

Tags: android, mobile, native

I'm trying to develop a mobile app. After trying PhoneGapp alongside with Ripple Emulator in Chrome and jQuery Mobile, I've come to the conclusion that the whole hybrid thing wont work for me. I feel way too restricted by jQuery framework. I'm looking forward to create something native but my problem right now is that I don't have a working device. I tried Android Studio but it is too slow on my machine. I'm running a slow AMD. What can I develop with?

Answer (score 0):

Try Genymotion. Genymotion is pretty simple to use and much faster than AVD. Also it's free for personal use. Check it out: [link](https://www.genymotion.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Gennymotion that is an Android emulator based on Virtualbox. It can emulate specific devices(Nexus, Samsung, HTC...) and allows you to install/run/ test apps.Because Virtualbox is cross-platform compatible, You can use it on Windows, Mac or Linux.

It is free for personal using. You can download the installer after registration in [here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/auth/signin)